# Saddle Wash and take care and Maintenance

Tags: maintenance, saddle

Can I wash saddle with soapy water? How can I take care of my saddle?

My saddle is the GT MTB Saddle, which is made from synthetic materials.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of saddle.

Leather saddles should generally be kept away from water and conditioned periodically. There are many pages on maintaining a leather saddle such as [this one](http://sheldonbrown.com/leather.html) and [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/how-do-i-maintain-a-brooks-leather-saddle?rq=1) and [this FAQ](http://www.brooksengland.com/getting-in-touch/faqs/saddle_maintenance/) from Brooks -- see the documentation that came with your saddle (or find the details from the manufacturer.

Plastic/Vinyl/other synthetics are generally quite hardy and should be fine with a gentle soap and water (but check with the manufacturer of the saddle -- yours may be different). They generally don't require any upkeep. While probably not ideal, I normally use a Clorox or Lysol wipe on my saddle when I wake up and find that a squirrel has defecated on my saddle -- I'm not entirely sure what makes squirrels like bicycle saddles.